# Unable to connect build service to TFS2013: Error TF30063 You are not authorized

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs

I have TFS 2013 Update 3 installed on a machine and I'm trying to configure the TFS Build service on another machine on the same domain. The registration of the build service completes successfully but the service, controller, and build agents go into an endless start/stop/restart loop. The event viewer on the build machine gives the following error in the Build Services Operational log:

```
Build machine 'x' lost connectivity to message queue tfsmq://buildservicehost-18/.
Reason: TF30063: You are not authorized to access http://tfs2013:8080/tfs/defaultcollection.
```

Things I have tried:

- Both NetworkService account and a domain account for the build configuration
- Unregistering/re-registering the build service
- Uninstalling TFS on build machine and reinstalling
- Creating a fresh server 2012 install, installing TFS build component on it

The domain account I tried to use was in the build service account group for the collection and I've even tried putting it in the admin group. I also tried running it as my own domain account which is a tfs admin and domain admin account. All with the same results. The fact that this occurred on 2 different machines, one with a completely fresh everything install leads me to believe the problem is on the TFS application tier itself but I have no idea where to go from here. Visual studio is able to connect to TFS just fine for all users.

Comment: If an error is occurring on the app tier there will be something in the event log...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up resolving this by doing the following:

1. Detach Collection
2. Backup Collection as a precaution
3. Uninstall TFS 2013 from the App Tier (which is also the Data Tier)
4. Re-install TFS 2013 and configure it for single server like it was without creating a collection
5. Attach the existing collection
6. Uninstall TFS on the build server
7. Re-install TFS on the build server and configure the service, controller, and agents.

This worked fine and didn't cause me to lose anything. I still don't understand why I was having problems in the first place but my only guess is that it was some type of remnant from doing a migration based upgrade from TFS 2010.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a TFS 2012 server that you are trying to connect a TFS 2013 build agent to. This is not a supported configuration.

It is recommended that your build Agents version of TFS matched the version on the server. This does not mean that you can't build with any version of MSBuild or VS that you want on that agent. That's configuration.

Comment: Definitely both the 2013 update 3 on app tier and build machine.

Comment: Yep. Next I'm going to try uninstalling the app tier and reinstalling it.